# Collision detection java applet with walls doesn't work correctly

Tags: java

The code shown below is a green ball with collision detection on the walls.

Is there any way I can improve it?

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Launcher extends Applet implements Runnable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private final int WIDTH = 50;
    private final int HIEGHT = 50;

    private int x = 5, velX = 1;
    private int y = 5, velY = 1;


    public void init() {

        this.setSize(800, 600);
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {

            if (x > this.getWidth() - WIDTH) {
                velX = -velX;
            }
            if (x < 0 + WIDTH / 2) {
                x = 0 + WIDTH / 2;
                velX = -velX;
            } else {
                x += velX;
            }
            if (y > this.getHeight() - HIEGHT) {

                velY = -velY;
            }
            if (y < 0 + HIEGHT / 2) {
                y = 0 + HIEGHT / 2;
                velY = -velY;
            } else {
                y += velY;
            }
            repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(17);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void start() {
        Thread thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    public void stop() {
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillOval(x, y, WIDTH, HIEGHT);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't just post a link to your code.  Copy the *relevant* parts into your question.  Not everybody can access remote links, and there is no guarantee that the link will stay alive in the long term.

Comment: Also, please state a specific problem if you have one. The collision detection doesn't work? What does it do that is incorrect?

Comment: sorry i try to post the code and no matter what i do it doent like it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because asking for a blanket review is **off topic**, either ask a specific quesiton or ask for a code review @ http://codereview.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The ball never reached the left/top borders but would half cross the right/bottom border as you were checking mixing the top/left and center co-ordinates between checking bounds and drawing. I've fixed that so you only use the top/left corner (and made it so if it goes past the borders then it recalculates the position as if it had bounced).
- When repainting the canvas you were clearing everything and redrawing. If you override the `update(Graphics)` method and just clear where the ball was then there is much less to redraw and it is (a bit) smoother.

Like this:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Test extends Applet implements Runnable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private final int SIZE = 50;
    private final int VELOCITY = 1;

    private int x = 5, velX = VELOCITY;
    private int y = 5, velY = VELOCITY;


    @Override
    public void init() {
        this.setSize(800, 600);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            x += velX;
            if (x > this.getWidth() - SIZE) {
                x = 2*(this.getWidth() - SIZE)-x;
                velX = -velX;
            }
            else if (x < 0) {
                x = -x;
                velX = -velX;
            }

            y += velY;
            if (y > this.getHeight() - SIZE) {
                y = 2*(this.getHeight() - SIZE)-y;
                velY = -velY;
            }
            else if (y < 0) {
                y = -y;
                velY = -velY;
            }
            repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(17);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Graphics g)
    {
        g.clearRect(
                x - VELOCITY,
                y - VELOCITY,
                SIZE+2*VELOCITY,
                SIZE+2*VELOCITY
        );
        paint(g);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillOval(x, y, SIZE, SIZE);
    }
}
```